# Django: Show different button in template if user object exists

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-views

I want to show one button if a user has already added an object, and another button if he/she hasn't.

In my template I have:

```
         <tr>
          {% for word in dict_list %}
          <td>{{word.target_word}} </td>
          <td>{{word.source_word}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="javascript:" class="add-word btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-wordpk="{{word.pk}}">Add</a>
         {% if user_word %}
            <a href="" class="add-word btn btn-success btn-sm" >Added</a>
         {% endif %}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

And in my views:

```
def custom_create_word(request, object):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    if request.method =="GET":
        from .forms import WordForm
        from .models import Word
        word = Word.objects.get(pk=object)
        user = request.user
        target_word = word.target_word
        source_word = word.source_word
        deck_name = "My Words"
        fluency = 0
        new_word, created = Word.objects.get_or_create(user=user, target_word=target_word,
                                     source_word=source_word, deck_name=deck_name, fluency=fluency)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vocab:dict'))

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(custom_create_word, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if Word.objects.filter(target_word=target_word, user=user).exists():
            user_word == True
            context['user_word'] = user_word
        return context
```

I don't get any errors, but I don't get the desired result either. Am I going about it the wrong way?

**Updated template:**

```
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          {% for word in dict_list %}
          <td>{{word.target_word}}</td>
          <td>{{word.source_word}}</td>
          <td>
          {% if user_word %}
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >Added</a>
          {% else %}
              <a href="javascript:" class="add-word btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-wordpk="{{word.pk}}">Add</a>
         {% endif %}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

**Updated views:**

```
class Dictionary(FilterView):
    model = Word
    template_name = 'vocab/dictionary.html'
    context_object_name = 'dict_list'
    paginate_by = 15
    filterset_class = WordFilter
    strict = False

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(user__username__iexact='special_user')
        return qs

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = qs
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        if pk is None:
            raise AttributeError('pk expected in url')
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = WordFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        word = Word.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        target_word = word.target_word
        context['user_word'] = Word.objects.filter(target_word=target_word, user=self.request.user).exists()
        return context
```

**Update**: If I hard code the pk in the above, I get the desired result, i.e. Add if word doesn't exist, and Added if it does. But the `pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')` doesn't work, I get DoesNotExist error - what should it be? How can I get access to each object's pk in the ListView?

urls.py:

```
 app_name='vocab'

    urlpatterns = [
        path("index/",views.VocabHome.as_view(),name='index'),
        path("list/", views.WordList.as_view(), name="list"),
        path("create/", views.CreateWord.as_view(), name="create"),
        re_path(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.WordDetail.as_view(),name="detail"),
        re_path(r"delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.WordDelete.as_view(),name="delete"),
        re_path(r"edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.WordUpdate.as_view(),name="edit"),
        path('dictionary/', views.Dictionary.as_view(),name='dict'),
        path("<int:object>/",views.custom_create_word,name="add-custom"),
    ]
```

**I've also now tried the following:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = WordFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    special_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user__username__iexact='special_user', target_word='target_word')
    logged_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, target_word='target_word')
    user_word = None
    if special_user_word == logged_user_word:
        user_word = True
    context['user_word'] = user_word
    return context
```

But I get `None` everywhere... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's `user_word = True`, not `user_word == True`.

Also in your template you should use the `else` clause otherwise when `user_word` is `True` you'll have 2 buttons.

Finally, `def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):` will not be executed because you are using a function as a view. `get_context_data` is for generic class based views. And even if it *were* executed, which I guess it's not, `target_word` that you use in it is not defined.

**Update for you new problem**

replace
`word = Word.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`
with
`word = Word.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))`

Comment: I had it like that originally and it didn't work. I changed it to '==' just to see if it would maybe work.

Comment: Please provide exactly what is the error you get. For example what's inside your `user_word` variable

Comment: Like I said, there is no error. But when I put `{{user_word}}` in the template, nothing appears. So there must be something wrong in my views, but I don't know what.

Comment: You're right, it was in the wrong view. Please see my updated question, especially updated views. It works now if I hard code it, but how can I get the pk correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the url's file, in the updated view i don't see how the function is getting called and which function is called.

Comment: I've added it now.

Comment: in the new django the url is changes to as below.

Comment: re_path("edit/<int:pk>",views.WordUpdate.as_view(),name="edit"),

Comment: Okay, but that has nothing to do with my question.